# make content visible in only one page

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I currently am working on a Zendesk Helpdesk site, and unfortunately have gotten no answers from them, so I am hoping I can have some success here.

I am looking to add a widget to my page, its an iFrame. Now, in the page editor in Zendesk, I added the iFrame code to the HTML for the "Categories" template page, but now it is shown in all categories. The categories page has 2 sections, Knowledgebase and Documents. I want the iFrame to only be visible in the Documents section.

Pretty much what I need is for the iFrame to be hidden in the "knowledgebase" section. any input would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a css class to the knowledge base section `div` or any tag you have and make the iframe `display:none`.

```
.knowledgebase iframe{display:none}
```

This can be achieved only if the iframe is inside the knowledgebase class div tag.

If the iframe is appended to the body then if possible add that class to the body tag if you cannot modify your body tag then write a small snippet in javascript

```
$("body").addClass("knowledgebase");
```